# Query to fetch most recent and highest activity of user

Tags: mysql, select, join, inner-join

My table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `scores` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nick` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `count` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL DEFAULT '00000',
    `messages` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL DEFAULT '00000',
    `dated` DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `nick_dated` (`nick`, `dated`),
    INDEX `nick` (`nick`),
    INDEX `count` (`count`),
    INDEX `messages` (`messages`)
)
COMMENT='Chat scores'
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

I wish to write a query so that for a user input value of `nick`, I can generate the user's:

- Total count
- Average count
- Most recent day's count
- Date of highest count

The query I've written is:

```
SELECT s.`nick` AS `nick`,
    s.`count` AS `recent`,
    t.`total` AS `total`,
    t.`avrg` AS `avrg`,
    MAX(ss.`count`) AS `max`,
    ss.dated
FROM (
    SELECT `nick`,
        SUM(`count`) AS `total`,
        AVG(`count`) AS `avrg`,
        MAX(`dated`) AS `dated` # For most recent activity
    FROM `scores`
    WHERE `nick` = 'hjpotter92'
) AS `t`
INNER JOIN scores s
    ON s.nick = t.nick
        AND s.dated = t.dated
INNER JOIN scores ss
    ON ss.nick = t.nick
```

I'm able to select the first three required values. But how would I be able to get the *date of highest activity*. Here's a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb773/1). As you can see in the fiddle DDL, **line #24**

```
INSERT INTO `scores` 
    (`count`, `nick`, `dated`) 
VALUES 
    (00052, 'hjpotter92', '2013-07-29');
```

The date with highest count (fetched by `MAX(ss.count)` correctly as 52) is `2013-07-29`, but my select query returns me *`July, 26 2013`*.

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is a strange mixture of aggregations.  Here is a version that works:

```
SELECT s.`nick` AS `nick`,
    srecent.`count` AS `recent`,
    t.`total` AS `total`,
    t.`avrg` AS `avrg`,
    t.maxcount,
    s.dated
FROM (SELECT `nick`,
             SUM(`count`) AS `total`,
             AVG(`count`) AS `avrg`,
             MAX(`dated`) AS `dated`, # For most recent activity
             max(count) as maxcount
      FROM `scores`
      WHERE `nick` = 'hjpotter92'
      group by nick
     )  `t` INNER JOIN
    scores s
    ON s.nick = t.nick AND
       s.count = t.maxcount join
    scores srecent
    on srecent.nick = t.nick and
       srecent.dated = t.dated;
```

The problem with your original query was the `max(count)` in the `select`.  This turned the outer `select` into an aggregation query -- one that returned one row.  However, the join on `ss` returned multiple rows, so an arbitrary row was returned from that join.  Hence the inconsistent results.

This version calculates the various aggregation values in the subquery.  It then joins back to the original table to get other information from those dates.

An alternative way of formulating the query is to use the `substring_index(group_concat())` trick:

```
SELECT `nick`,
       substring_index(group_concat(count order by dated desc), ',', 1) as mostrecent,
       SUM(`count`) AS `total`,
       AVG(`count`) AS `avrg`,
       max(count) as maxcount,
       substring_index(group_concat(dated order by count desc), ',', 1) as dated
FROM `scores`
WHERE `nick` = 'hjpotter92'
group by nick;
```

Comment: In the first answer I think you should still group by nick in the subquery, since you're using aggregate functions.

Comment: @Ruben . . . It is not strictly necessary, but I agree.  It clarifies the query and makes it more robust should more than one "nick" be chosen.

Comment: Neat trick with the substring_index(group_concat()) by the way.

Comment: I wouldn't attempt to answer another since Gordon is here. +1

Comment: I am using the first one. Though `SUBSTRING_INDEX` trick is quite nice, the code will be handed down to juniors and I don't want them to question me later. :)